# Why is a CPMG sequence more resilient to errors in the pulse amplitudes than a CP sequence?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, decoherence, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

In the context of NMR (or in general qubits nowadays), a CP sequence is a refocussing sequence that looks like X/2 - X^n - X/2. A CPMG sequence instead is X/2 - Y^n - X/2. This change of axes is in fact the main contribution of MG, see https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1716296 (or so I take from the abstract, I cannot access it). If I read the literature there are some pros and cons, but it is stated that CPMG is more resilient to errors in the pulses and is almost always preferable.

See for example this image for a graphic representation
[image]

Why is this the case, intuitively? How does rotating the initial and final pulse provide resilience against errors in the pulse amplitudes?